# How do I tell what's happening when I postback my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with MVC 4 EF Code First and I have an object with an Edit View and it works properly.  Then I created a very similar Create View, only when I click on the submit button I don't hit any breakpoints in the Controller.  How do I tell what's wrong here?  Is there somewhere I can set a breakpoint in either JavaScript or code-behind?

**Model**

```
public class ThirdParty : BaseModel
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    private String CountryCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(6)]
    private Int32 SequenceNumber { get; set; }

    public String UIN 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (CountryCode != null && SequenceNumber > 0)
                return CountryCode.ToString() + "-" + SequenceNumber.ToString();
            else
                return null;
        }
        set
        {
            CountryCode = value.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
            SequenceNumber = Int32.Parse(value.ToString().Substring(3, value.Length-3));
        }

    }

    [MaxLength(250)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RelationshipType> RelationshipTypes { get; set; }

    // Address
    public Int32 AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public bool IsImported { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }

    // constructor
    public ThirdParty()
    {
        RelationshipTypes = new HashSet<RelationshipType>();
        Attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>();
    }
}
```

**Controller Methods**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();
        ThirdParty model = context.ThirdParties.Find(id);
        ViewBag.Countries = context.Countries.ToList<Country>();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(string button, ThirdParty model, int id)
    {
        if (button == "cancel")
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();


            model.Address.Country = context.Countries.Find(model.Address.CountryId);
            context.Entry(model.Address.Country).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.Entry(model.Address).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            context.SaveChanges();

            Success("Third Party record updated!");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();
            model.Address = context.Addresses.Find(model.AddressId);
            return View("Edit", model);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();
        ViewBag.Countries = context.Countries.ToList<Country>();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ThirdParty model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();
            List<ThirdParty> models = context.ThirdParties.ToList<ThirdParty>();
            model.Id = models.Count() == 0 ? 1 : models.Select(x => x.Id).Max() + 1;
            context.ThirdParties.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();

            Success("Your information was saved!");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Error("There were some errors in your form.");
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string button, ThirdParty model)
    {
        if (button == "cancel")
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ThirdPartyContext context = new ThirdPartyContext();
            List<ThirdParty> models = context.ThirdParties.ToList<ThirdParty>();
            model.Id = models.Count() == 0 ? 1 : models.Select(x => x.Id).Max() + 1;
            context.ThirdParties.Add(model);
            context.SaveChanges();

            Success("Your information was saved!");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        Error("There were some errors in your form.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Edit View**

```
@model Models.ThirdParty

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/ContentLayout.cshtml";
}


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Third Party</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-8">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ThirdParty", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Address.Id)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UIN)
        <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)
    @Html.Partial("_EditAddress", Model)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModifiedOn)

    <p>
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </p>
}

    </div>
</div>
```

** Create View **

```
@model Models.ThirdParty

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/ContentLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <ul class="breadcrumb" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <li><a href="#">Third Parties</a></li>
            <li class="active">Create New Third Party</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Create Third Party</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ThirdParty", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UIN)

            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AddressId)
            @Html.Partial("_EditAddress", Model)

            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModifiedBy)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ModifiedOn)

            <p>
                <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" title="Submit" />
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        }
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I may have left out a critical part.  I have these 4 hidden fields on the ThirdParty and Address models that I am planning to set in the controller Create method (if I can ever get in there).  Here's the Model:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Int32 CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public Int32 ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

I was thinking that maybe my view is invalid and that's why it's not sending it to the controller.  Here's how these look in the page markup:

```
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CreatedBy must be a number." data-val-required="The CreatedBy field is required." id="Address_CreatedBy" name="Address.CreatedBy" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreatedOn must be a date." data-val-required="The CreatedOn field is required." id="Address_CreatedOn" name="Address.CreatedOn" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ModifiedBy must be a number." data-val-required="The ModifiedBy field is required." id="Address_ModifiedBy" name="Address.ModifiedBy" type="hidden" value="" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ModifiedOn must be a date." data-val-required="The ModifiedOn field is required." id="Address_ModifiedOn" name="Address.ModifiedOn" type="hidden" value="" />



        <div class="form-group">
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field CreatedBy must be a number." data-val-required="The CreatedBy field is required." id="CreatedBy" name="CreatedBy" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field CreatedOn must be a date." data-val-required="The CreatedOn field is required." id="CreatedOn" name="CreatedOn" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ModifiedBy must be a number." data-val-required="The ModifiedBy field is required." id="ModifiedBy" name="ModifiedBy" type="hidden" value="" />
            <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ModifiedOn must be a date." data-val-required="The ModifiedOn field is required." id="ModifiedOn" name="ModifiedOn" type="hidden" value="" />
        </div>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I have found in most cases my edit and create views are the same. I just look for the record id and update or insert accordingly

Comment: I am using Chrome & IE 8.  I tried changing the action to Edit instead of Create actually.  It must be something I'm missing about the Create.

Comment: So, it turns out it was the Created and Modified hidden fields that were not set.  To get the submit to work I had to create an instance of the ThirdParty object and populate these fields in both the ThirdParty and Address objects and return that from my Create() Action in order to get the save to work.  How do I find out all of the validations that are failing?  Is there a summary validator that can list all of the fields that are not set so that it doesn't look like nothing happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your action gets called, setting a breakpoint at the beginning of your action and attaching to the process should do the trick.
Have you made sure that a POST request is sent from the browser when you click submit on your Create page ?

I haven't tried to run your code but note that you have defined two Create actions with the same name to process the POST verb.

This is likely to be ambiguous for the ASP.NET MVC as it cannot figure out what action to call.

Also, you are defining a ReturnUrl route value in the following line:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ThirdParty", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

This doesn't seem to be used in your action handling the POST.

Why do you have 2 submit buttons with the values "submit" and "create" ?

You can remove the Create action that takes the extra button parameter and replace the markup:

```
<button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                <input name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit" title="Submit" />
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
```

with something like:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("Index", "ThirdParty")">Cancel</a>
<input name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create" title="Create" />
```

I invite you to read more [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs) on how ASP.NET MVC Routing works.

Comment: Let me explain, I have multiple buttons to show that I tried both the standard 'input' button, as well as the 'button' approach.  When I click on either of these nothing happens (no network activity in Chrome Network tab dev tools).  I removed the HttpPost action that just takes a ThirdParty for an argument so that I now only have a single HttpPost Create method as well.  I don't know what the ReturnUrl is in the BeginForm() for, so I just replaced that with a null.

Comment: The cancel button that you suggested works.  And if I click on any of my submit buttons without entering values for required fields, the validation triggers.  But, after entering values and clicking on any of the submit buttons it doesn't look like anything is happening at all.

Comment: What is the action the form posts to in the generated HTML ?
Does it look right to you ?

Do you have any client side validation that would prevent the form from posting ? Try to disable the client side validation maybe.

Comment: I am only using EF for the client side validation.  If I don't provide values for the hidden fields the form doesn't post, which I guess makes sense.  I would like to catch all the client validation errors on the page in a single summary box so that this doesn't happen in the future.

Comment: I think you are getting confused. 
Entity Framework doesn't provide any javascript validation.
Empty hidden fields are not going to prevent a form from posting.

Comment: It's possible that I am confused, I am using Bootstrap 3 with unobtrusive validation in my project.  So, when I do a create, these hidden fields are not set...so I was thinking that it may be preventing me from posting to the controller unless all the field validators are satisfied.

Comment: I still am not sure what is preventing the post back when the model is not valid, I'm assuming it's some javascript/ajax M$ magic on the page.  That being said, I appreciate your time and I'll accept your answer.